# Making a 15V transformer

Tags: power-supply, voltage, transformer

I presently have a transformer with 12V DC output.But I want to charge a 15V battery.So how can I make the 12V transformer to 15V ?

Comment: Are you sure it outputs 12V or did you emasure it? Many 12V wall-wart type transformers will output >> 12V when loaded lightly.

Comment: A transformer does not have a DC output. So what, exactly do you have? A power supply?

Comment: The question title is misleading, as a suggestion it might be better to phrase it more along the lines of "Finding a 15v supply," depending on what you actually have. Using transformer is misleading (typically people don't know the difference, so don't worry).

Answer (score 1):

Boost converter. Lots of cheap fully assembled ones out there. Will take from as low as three volts and boost up to fifteen or more. See LM2577.
Doc

Answer (score 0):

Transformer can only step up from AC to AC.
Boost Converter is used for step up directly from Dc to Dc.
you can easily see that how a boost converter works on the link below.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_converter

Answer (score 0):

IFF your transformer is a 50HZ type and if its not filtered which may be the case then placing an electrolytic cap of say 1000microfarad 25V across the output will give you more than 15V this means a linear reg or a buck convertor

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you don't already know, battery charging isn't quite as simple as connecting a battery to a power supply at the battery output voltage.

Many batteries are easily damaged, and lithium in particular likes to catch fire.

Check out the battery charging application guide from your favorite vendor. They'll walk you through the devices to use.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can take the transformer, put a couple of windings on top to make up for the difference in voltage and put them in series with the 12V windings.

**Otoh it is probably cheaper and more efficient to just buy a transformer that suits your needs.**